# Update(Put) no meu projeto não grava no BD(MongoDB)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-6

Preciso fazer uma tela de edição e não estou conseguindo. Veja como está minha component(Eliminei os imports para poupar espaço)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-operators',
  templateUrl: './operators.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./operators.component.css'],
  providers: [OperatorService]
})

export class OperatorsComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['codigo', 'nome'];
  private operUrl: 'api/Operators';

  public message: string;
  public dataSource: Model.Itens[];
  createForm :FormGroup;

  public form:any;


  constructor(private _operService: OperatorService, private builder: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.onGet();
  }

  onDelete(operator: Model.Itens) {
    debugger;
    if (confirm('Deseja excluir o operador: ' + operator.name + '?')) {

      this._operService
        .delete<any>(operator.operatorId)
        .subscribe((res) => {
          this.onGet();
        });
    }
  }

  onGet() {
    this._operService
      .getAll<Model.Result<Model.Itens>>()
      .subscribe((data: Model.Result<Model.Itens>) => {
        debugger;
        this.dataSource = data.itens;
      });
  }

  initEditOperator(operator: any){
    operator.edit = true;
    this.form = this.builder.group({
      id: operator.id,
      name: operator.name
    });
  }

  checkEdit() {
    if (this.dataSource == null || this.dataSource.length == 0) return false;
      return this.dataSource.filter((item: any) => item.edit === true).length == 0;
  }

  onUpdate(){

    this._operService.update<Model.Result<Model.Itens>>(this.form.id, this.form.name)
    .subscribe(success =>{
        // if(success.Result){

        // }
      },
        error =>{
      } 
    );

  }
}
```

esse é o html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <caption>Lista de Operadores</caption>
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Código</th>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let operator of dataSource">
                        <form *ngIf="operator.edit != true">
                            <td>{{ operator.operatorId}}</td>
                            <td>{{ operator.name }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <fa *ngIf="checkEdit()" name="pencil" (click)="initEditOperator(operator)"></fa>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <fa *ngIf="checkEdit()" name="times" (click)="onDelete(operator)"></fa>
                            </td>
                        </form>
                        <div *ngIf="operator.edit === true">
                            <td> {{ operator.operatorId}}<input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="operator.operatorId"></td>
                            <td> <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="operator.name"></td>
                            <td>
                                <fa name="save" (click)="onUpdate()"></fa>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <fa name="ban" (click)="operator.edit = null;"></fa>
                            </td>
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A chamada no **HTML** está no **(OnClick)=onUpdate()**

Essa é a minha service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OperatorService {

  private actionUrl: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private _configuration: Configuration) {
        this.actionUrl = _configuration.ServerWithApiUrl + 'Operators/';
    }

    public getAll<T>(): Observable<T> {
      return this.http.get<T>(this.actionUrl);
  }

  public getSingle<T>(id: number): Observable<T> {
      return this.http.get<T>(this.actionUrl + id);
  }

  public add<T>(itemName: string): Observable<T> {
      const toAdd = JSON.stringify({ ItemName: itemName });

      return this.http.post<T>(this.actionUrl, toAdd);
  }

  public update<T>(id: string, itemToUpdate: any): Observable<T> {
      return this.http
          .put<T>(this.actionUrl + id, JSON.stringify(itemToUpdate));
  }

  public delete<T>(id: string): Observable<T> {
      return this.http.delete<T>(this.actionUrl + id);
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class CustomInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (!req.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
            req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
        }

        req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json') });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers));
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

Minha **Model**

```
declare namespace Model{
    export interface Result<T>{
        error: boolean,
        itens: Array<T>,
        message: string
    }

    export interface Itens{
        operatorId: string,
        name: string,
    }
}
```

Consigo ver as alterações na tela e tudo mais, mas ao dar um F5 na página, aí volta como estava, isso é devido a não gravar no banco de dados. Uso MongoDB, mas o que está acontecendo não tem nada a ver com o mongo, por isso não adicionei a tag dele.

Quando chamo a rotina, debugando no browser, tenho esse erro

> PUT http://localhost:56758/api/Operators/undefined 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Coloca um console.log() dentro do seu método de  update para ver se o parâmetro está chegando undefined. Em algum momento você está perdendo o valor do seu parâmetro, por isso está undefined na rota.

Comment: O not found entendi, mas não consigo gravar. Quando eu coloco um **formControlName** no html, zoa tudo. Estou lendo a documentação do formControl e entender seu uso, mas falta um entendimento para concluir a tarefa que já era pra ter concluído.

Comment: @GabrielaMendonça, valeu pela dica. Vou fazer isso sim e posto o result.

Comment: @pnet, funcionou?

Comment: Ainda não testei, pois preciso terminar outras telas primeiro, mas acredito que até ao final do dia eu testo.